# Sort transactions in temporal order

Tags: transaction, iota-network

I want to sort transactions, within a specific tag, in temporal order. In [the docs](https://domschiener.gitbooks.io/iota-guide/content/chapter1/transactions-and-bundles.html) it says:

> `timestamp` : `Int` timestamp of the transaction. It is important to know
>   that timestamps in IOTA are not enforced.

Is there a convention regarding the time zones to be used? And what's about `attachmentTimestamp`? On which of the time-related fields, `timestamp` or `attachmentTimestamp`, should I relay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Timestamps in transactions are expected to be unix timestamps. [Unix timestamps are timezone independent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062515/do-unix-timestamps-change-across-timezones).

Most importantly, timestamps are set by the client (i.e. the sender) and nothing in the protocol guarantees that they are correct. So relying on timestamp/attachmentTimestamp to re-order the transactions is probably not the best option (unless you have complete control of the client).

If you need ordered messages, you can look at [Masked Authenticated Messaging (MAM)](https://blog.iota.org/introducing-masked-authenticated-messaging-e55c1822d50e) were in addition to strict message ordering you also have (optional) encryption of the data.